# constexpr operator overloading of class templates

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-meta-programming, constexpr

I am working with template meta programming techniques, and I'm just playing around with different methods of doing things at the moment. Here is the code:

```
template<const int A>
struct iwrapper
{
    static const int num = A;
};

template<int A, int B>
constexpr iwrapper<A+B> operator+(iwrapper<A>, iwrapper<B>)
{
    return iwrapper<iwrapper<A>::num + iwrapper<B>::num>();
}

int main()
{
    constexpr iwrapper<2> first;
    constexpr iwrapper<4> second;

    constexpr auto answer = first + second;
}
```

When I try to run this, it gives me this error message:

```
error: the value of 'first' is not usable in a constant expression
```

Can someone help me figure out why? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see problems in your code and it compiles without problems with my clang++ 3.8.1.

But I have your same error with my g++ 6.3.0.

Trying with newer versions of g++ (starting from g++ 7.1.0) the error disappear.

So I suppose that the error is a bug in olds versions of g++, corrected from g++ 7.1.0.

Comment: I am observing the same behavior of g++ 6.3.0. Interestingly, the error message disappears after explicitly defaulting the constructor `iwrapper() = default;`. Alternatively, passing the arguments to `operator+` by value helps, too.

Comment: The error also goes away by using `constexpr iwrapper<2> first{};` i.e. changing `first` to `first{}`. Might be related to [this GCC bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58969)